# Join Table with the id of another join table

Tags: mysql, cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.0

i'm currently trying to build a backend for a project. In this project you will be able to create "ContentElements" that can be used to display content in a page (in my case Sites). Every ContentElement can have multiple options. When a user creates a new Site with an ContentElement (e.g. header) he would enter all options of the element. For example:

```
"src": "/img/bg.jpg",
"text": "Lorem ipsum..."
```

In order to save the option's value per page it is used in, i store these values in a separate table (content_elements_sites_values).

My scheme currently looks like this: [data scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXLIj.png)

So what i'm currently trying to do is when i get all data associated with the Site i also want to get the data from 'content_elements_sites_values'

```
$site = $this->Sites->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Templates', 'Colors', 'SiteTypes', 'ContentElements' => [
            'ContentElementOptions' => [
                'ContentElementsSitesValues'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'conditions' => [
            // Just to explain my problem.
            'ContentElementsSites.id' => 'ContentElementsSitesValues.content_elements_sites_id'
        ]
    ]);
```

I really don't know if this is even possible or even if my "design" is a total bull***t. But i cannot think of another way to store the filled in data. I'm very open to suggestions of a better way to store this data. Please ask if you need further information in order to help me.

Thank you in advance!

---

**EDIT**

I try to explain better what i want to achieve.

Every **site** can have multiple **content_elements** of the same type (association is stored in **content_elements_sites** junction table).
Every **content_element** can have multiple **content_element_options**

All **content_element_options** and **content_elements** are defined by an Admin.

Another user can create a **site** and populate it with **content_elements** and enter **content_elements_sites_value** for all **content_element_options**. And as the same **content_element** (e.g. a paragraph or a list) can have multiple occurrences in the same site, i'll need to store every **content_elements_sites_value** the user entered.

Thats why i created the link between **content_elements_sites** and **content_element_options**.

Currently i'm using this query to get everything expect the value:

```
$site = $this->Sites->find('all', [
        'conditions' => [
            'Sites.id' => $id
        ],
        'contain' => ['ContentElements' => [
                'sort' => [
                    'ContentElementsSites.order' => 'ASC'
                ],
                'ContentElementOptions' => [
                    'ContentElementsSitesValues' => [
                        'conditions' => [
                            'ContentElementsSitesValues.content_elements_sites_id' => 'ContentElementsSites.id',
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

This results in empty **content_elements_sites_values**

```
(int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\ContentElementOption) {
    'id' => (int) 7,
    'content_element_id' => (int) 1,
    'name' => 'Test',
    'json_name' => 'test',
    'option_type_id' => (int) 1,
    'content_elements_sites_value' => null,             
}
```

My scheme currently looks like this: [data scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXLIj.png)

I'm wondering if this query is even possible. Or if the whole thing is just too flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have defined the relationships signifies that you wish to have a very modular approach so that *a content element* can be used with multiple sites and *a content element option* can be used with multiple content elements.

If that is the case, schema direction looks okay with few changes :

1) **content_elements_sites_values** table can have **site_id** column directly instead of *content_elements_sites_id* column as site will be always unique for an entry in that table so the connection id of *content_elements_sites* isn't required.

2) *content_elements_sites_values* table can be renamed to **content_element_options_values**.

3) You can remove **id** column from *content_elements_sites* and *content_elements_sites_values* junction tables.

Comment: But it would not be possible to have multiple occurrences of a _content_element_ in the same page if i set the **site_id** in **content_elements_sites_values**. I'll update my question because i did not make that clear – sorry. But you are right its going to be very flexible. And this gives me a headache :)

Comment: I see. then, you can continue with **content_elements_sites_id**. As far as query is concerned, you should use **matching()** instead of *contain()* because you want to limit the main table results based on association conditions. Go step by step here - fetch 2 associations first, check query in debug kit, fire it directly in database, make changes if needed and then add 3rd association to it and repeat. [Ref](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#retrieving-associated-data)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you are looking for :

```
$site = $this->Sites->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Templates', 'Colors', 'SiteTypes', 'ContentElements', 'ContentElements.ContentElementOptions','ContentElements.ContentElementOptions.ContentElementsSitesValues'],
....]);
```

dont forget to define association relationship in model table.

Comment: But this is just another way of writing the same query. Im currently trying to rephrase my question.